# Problem with submitting dependent job in slurm

Tags: bash, slurm, sbatch

I'm using the following `.sh` script to submit some `Slurm` jobs.

```
# Set hardware resource requests
nb_partitions=200 # number of distinct partitions to which you'll send sbatch statements
nb_threads=7 # number of CPUs requested per partition

# Make directory in which you'll store results
mkdir results
 
# Make a separate folder for each partition
for j in $(seq 1 $nb_partitions)
do
      mkdir results/partition$j
done

# Copy MainFolder which has code for execution to each partition folder and change partition number stored in each input file to correspond to its number
for i in $(seq 1 $nb_partitions)
do
      cp -r MainFolder results/partition$i
      sed -i "1s/.*/${i[@]}/g" results/partition$i/MainFolder/partition_nb.txt
done
echo "Files and folders have been copied and created."

# Loop to submit simulations job for each partition
slurmids="" # storage of slurm job ids
for k in $(seq 1 $nb_partitions)
do
      cd results/partition$k/MainFolder
      # Write parameters to files within the main folder so they can be read into FORTRAN
      echo "$nb_partitions" >> nb_partitions.txt
      echo "$nb_threads" >> nb_threads.txt
      slurmids="$slurmids:$(sbatch --parsable --cpus-per-task=$nb_threads run.sh)"
      cd ..
      cd ..
      cd ..
done
echo "Jobs are now running."

# Submit job to combine files
ID=$(sbatch --dependency=afterok=$slurmids combine_results.sh)
```

The final line of this code is supposed to submit a batch job that will execute only after all of the other jobs submitted in the loop are done. However, when I run this shell script the job `combine_results` in the final line of code never runs. The `Slurm` manager simply says the job is waiting because the dependencies are not satisifed.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: maybe not all jobs have finished successfully?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately I checked and they all finished successfully.

Comment: `dependency=afterok=$slurmids` should be `dependency=afterok:$slurmids`

Comment: Hi @MarcusBoden - unfortunately your response caused an error to be returned saying a valid dependency was not specified, but I did try ``dependency=afterok$slurmids`` and thinks worked well!